# Occlusion Material or Hold-Out Shader in ARKit and SceneKit

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, virtual-reality

I have seen some examples demo of ARKit where material A is blocking material B, kind of creating occlusion effect, or black hole, or masking. But all of them seems to be using Unity engine (I might be wrong). I wanted to do this using what Apple provide already. Or maybe using Metal Shader.

Wondering if anyone knows a trick that allows this for ARKit or even in SceneKit term, when 2 objects are overlapping, but wanting one object to occlude the other object, leaving the other object empty. It cannot be CSG right, because that would be too expensive?

Comment: Would be interesting to see if Apple supports occlusion in ARKit/SceneKit. From what limited amount I've seen of SceneKit so far, it seems like it doesn't? Occlusion math is complicated

Comment: Could you link to those examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To generate a hold-out mask, also known as `Occlusion Material`, use`.colorBufferWriteMask`, instance property that writes depth data when rendering the material.

```
sphere.geometry?.firstMaterial?.colorBufferWriteMask = []
```

Then assign an appropriate object's rendering order:

```
sphere.renderingOrder = -100
```

And, at last, allow SceneKit to read from / write to depth buffer when rendering the material:

```
sphere.geometry?.firstMaterial?.writesToDepthBuffer = true
sphere.geometry?.firstMaterial?.readsFromDepthBuffer = true

sphere.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
```

[image]