# RealityKit only displays dark images

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am working on an iOS App with ARKit 3 and RealityKit. I want to create virtual 2d planes within the room containing images. Therefore I used

[Adding a material to a ModelEntity programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56828648/adding-a-material-to-a-modelentity-programmatically)

But images which aren't nearly white will get displayed very dark, nearly black. I also tried out `UnlitMaterial`. It indeed created a little better result but the images are still way to dark. This problem persists over JPEG and PNG files.

On earlier versions where I used SceneKit I solved a similiar problem through

```
sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

I guess the image did enlight itself through this code.

How can I solve the problem in RealityKit?

Possibly related: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119265

Answer (score 2):

#### When scene lighting doesn’t affect a material

Out-of-the-box ARView has auto-lighting feature embedded in light estimation stage. However, sometimes, it doesn't work properly due to poor environment lighting. So, the only way for materials to ignore scene lighting, is to use UnlitMaterial or [VideoMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131206/realitykit-how-to-add-a-video-material-to-a-modelentity#comment110576442_58131206).

Also, make sure that your unlit material has `white` color and your `jpg` or `png` images have no special color profile. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        arView.renderOptions = [.disableGroundingShadows]

        var material = UnlitMaterial(color: .white)
        material.color.texture = .init(try! .load(named: "img", in: nil))

        let mesh = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.25)
        let model = ModelEntity(mesh: mesh, materials: [material])
        
        let anchor = AnchorEntity()
        anchor.addChild(model)
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 let img = UIImage(named: ouputSrc, in: Bundle(path: resourcePath), compatibleWith: nil)
                
  var myMaterial = UnlitMaterial()
  myMaterial.baseColor = try! .texture(.load(named: ouputSrc, in: Bundle(path: resourcePath)))
  myMaterial.tintColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1)
```